# aes encryption ,got error as undefined reference

Tags: c++, openssl, aes

When I use these functions `AES_cfb128_encrypt()` and  `AES_set_encrypt_key()` including oepnssl library I got error as

> undefined reference to AES_cfb128_encrypt() and undefined reference to
>   AES_encrypt_key().

Please tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: You should link your program with the openssl library.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to link your program with openssl. Just add the flag -lcrypto (thanks noloader) to your link command